# Given a folder with subdirectories, how can I delete everything (using PowerShell )within the subdirectories except for *.html and *.css

Tags: powershell, scripting

Given:

> MainFolder
>
> > Sub-directory1
> >
> > > index.html
> > >
> > > main.css
> > >
> > > images(folder)
> > >
> > > readme.text
> >
> > Sub-directory2
> >
> > > index.html
> > >
> > > main.css
> > >
> > > images(folder)
> > >
> > > readme.text

When the script runs I would need it to go through each sub-directory in the main folder(can be specified by a specific path) and delete everything except for .css and .html files, including folders.

I would expect the end result to look like the following:
Given:

> MainFolder
>
> > Sub-directory1
> >
> > > index.html
> > >
> > > main.css
> >
> > Sub-directory2
> >
> > > index.html
> > >
> > > main.css

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is follow the examples in the built-in help files for …

```
# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-help -Name Get-ChildItem -Online

(Get-Command -Name Remove-Item).Parameters
Get-help -Name Remove-Item -Examples
Get-help -Name Remove-Item -Full
Get-help -Name Remove-Item -Online    

# Get parameter that accept pipeline input
Get-Help Get-ChildItem -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select * 

Get-Help Remove-Item -Parameter * | 
Where-Object {$_.pipelineInput -match 'true'} | 
Select *
```

Specifically, take note of the -Exclude switch

Answer (score 0):

Nice and simple.
For each item, it checks to see if the extension does not equal `.html` or `.css` and removes them if it does not.

```
Get-ChildItem -File |
ForEach-Object { 
    If($_.Extension -ne ".html" -and $_.Extension -ne ".css") { 
        Remove-Item $_.FullName
    }
}
```